# I want to print the dictionary in python

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

```
l = {}
name = [(str, input().split()) for i in range(0, 15)]
dob = [(int, input().split()) for i in range(0, 15)]
print({name[i]:dob[i] for i in range(len(dob))})
```

I want to print 15 items in a dictionary format of name as key and dateofbirth(dob) as value.What wrong I am doing?
    .....................................................................................

```
the error is:
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                                
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>                                                                                             
    print({name[i]:dob[i] for i in range(len(dob))})                                                                              
  File "main.py", line 4, in <dictcomp>                                                                                           
    print({name[i]:dob[i] for i in range(len(dob))})                                                                              
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Comment: Your code is difficult to diagnose without the command line input. Please provide exact input.

Comment: (str, input().split()) for i in range(0, 15) this is taking 15 (string) inputs and splitting it.

Comment: This I got. What are the values you provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not in the print() function but in the way you make up the first list: instead of pulling out the names, it gives you a `(<class 'str'>, 'string')` tuple that cannot be used as a key for a dictionary. The same happens with the 'dob' variable, but the issue is only with keys.

Try doing:

```
name = [input() for i in range(0, 15)] #this takes and returns the input. no need to convert to string
dob = [int(input()) for i in range(0, 15)] #this takes an input and returns it's numeric value
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this (this returns a generator):

```
name = map(str, input().split())
dob = map(int, input().split())
print({n: d for n, d in zip(name, dob)})
```

If you want it to return a list instead:

```
name = list(map(str, input().split()))
dob = list(map(int, input().split()))
print({n: d for n, d in zip(name, dob)})
```

Comment: but why its returning object when I am trying to take 15 inputs from the user.

Comment: name = list(map(str, input().split()) for i in range(0, 15))    
dob = list(map(int, input().split()) for i in range(0, 15))
print({n: d for n, d in zip(name, dob)})

Comment: like this --------------   {<map object at 0x7fa36ecebc50>: <map object at 0x7fa36ecef160>}

Comment: Like I said, see my updated answer. That's by design.